# How to Pass a unpack iterator as an Argument to a Function?

Tags: python

I have a question about passing arguments in a function.
In python when you want to unpack an iterable obj on the right-hand side,  you have to do it within some context,  like a tuple or a set or etc.
For example,  you can not say:

```
a, b = *(1, 2)
```

and you should say:

```
a, b = (*(1, 2),) // a=1, b=2
```

or you can say:

```
a, b = {*(1, 2)} //a=1, b=2 or a=2, b=1
```

Am I rigth?

But when you want to unpack iterable and then pass it as arguments in a function, you do not need any context at all and you just unpack your iterable object.
For example:

```
def f(param1, param2):
     pass
f(*(1, 2))
```

and you do not need to use some kind of context like before. For example, you do not say:

```
f({*(1, 2)}) // it will be f({1, 2})
```

I think we don't use {} or any other context in this case because we were looking for pass 2 values as arguments in our f function. Thus, I assume we have to say `f(*(1, 2))` not `f({*(1, 2)})` .

If I was right, Could you please explain more about how f(*(1, 2)) is worked without using any context under the hood?

Comment: Why not just `a, b = (1, 2)`?

Comment: Also, the function call *is* the context you're looking for.

Comment: you can say  a, b = (1, 2) but I just explain about this matters if you want to use * in RH you have to use in within some context

Comment: That's not about "in RH". When you unpack `(1, 2)` into a set with `{*(1, 2)}`, or unpack it into another tuple with `(*(1, 2),)`, it doesn't matter that this expression happens to be on the right-hand side of an assignment. The `*` is part of the set or tuple construction syntax, not anything to do with the assignment.

Comment: Similarly, in `f(*(1, 2))`, the `*` is part of the function call syntax. `*` unpacking is not a standalone operator; it is part of the syntax for various kinds of expressions where it would make sense to unpack things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f(*(1, 2))` does have context! The context is the list (and dictionary) of function arguments itself. In essence, in a function call `f(...)` the stuff between the parentheses can be seen as a hybrid between a tuple and a dictionary literal (only using `x=4` instead of `'x': 4`), which then gets passed to the function:

```
>>> def f(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(args, kwargs)
>>> l = [10, 11]; d = {'a': 12, 'b': 13}
>>> f(1, *l, 2, 3, x=4, y=5, **d, z=6)
(1, 10, 11, 2, 3) {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'a': 12, 'b': 13, 'z': 6}
```

Viewed like this it makes perfect sense that you can unpack sequences and dictionaries into this context.

Comment: Tnx for your explanations. Could you please give me some references so I can dive into it?

Comment: @Sarah I don't know if this helps: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter. Other than that I don't know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for the context for the function itself that you were explained before.(list or dic)